# ¿Cómo mostrar solo un tipo de dato en Firebase?

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase, arraylist

estoy trabajando en Java y he podido localizar datos especificos en la base de datos para una aplicacion, lo que no se es que si se pueda obtener todos los nombres de name y guardarlos en un arreglo

Tengo una base de datos en Firebase y cree nodos como estos: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quería saber si existe alguna forma de guardar por ejemplo todos los nombres, el dato **name** en un arreglo. Por ejemplo que yo pueda leer solo los puros nombres.
name[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg0th.jpg)=pedro
name[2]=juan

Para así poder crear una lista de nombres dentro del programa y no en la base de datos porque ya están.

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0):

tienes varias opciones:
- bajarte todo el nodo Users y hacer un bucle para obtener todos sus nombres.
- Cuando creas o modificas un nuevo usuario, guardas también en otra "tabla" (nodo) el nombre. Yo te recomiendo asociarlo con su ID, algo así:

```
Names: {
     -LkhvofpdsfDfFSe: "Pepe",
     -LhkdifurldfseFD: "Manolo"
}
```

y así puedes solicitar todos los nombres del tirón.
Sin embargo, no entiendo para qué puedes querer los nombres sueltos de los usuarios, eso es un dato mas o menos privado...
Tampoco te preocupe usar la opción primera de bajarte todo el nodo Users, Firebase usa Sockets y el consumo es muy bajo.

Lo que sí te recomiendo es que separes tus datos en dos tablas, una con el ID y poco más (el nombre y el email por ejemplo) y otra con el resto de datos. Así podrías cargar tu mini tabla de referencia de Users, muy ligera, para los listados, y si un usuario concreto quiere acceder a sus datos, ya cargas sólo su nodo de la otra tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograrlo solo itera sobre la lista `User` y obtene el nombre de cada uno.

```
mDatabase.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    ArrayList nameArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

      String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
      nameArray.add(name);

       }

      Log.d("Nombres:",nameArray);

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

El for va a iterar por cada nodo dentro de User en busca del hijo name, al encontrarlo va a obtener su valor y almacenarlo dentro del array de tipo `String` `nameArray`, luego del for en un `Log.d (debug)` vas a obtener el array con los datos que recolecto.

Por otra parte `mDatabase` hace referencia a tu `DatabaseReference` que declaras en tu onCreate()

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

onCreate(){
...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

}
```

Si no queres hacer una escucha activa sobre los valores, podes reemplazar `. addValueEventListener` por `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`